# How to separate String into chars

Tags: c#, string, parsing, letters

```
public static string kw;

public String parse(String keyword)
{
    this.keyword = keyword;
    char[] letters = keyword.ToCharArray();
    string g;

    long length = System.Convert.ToInt64(keyword.Length.ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i <= length-1; i++)
    {
        kw = "/"+letters[i];
    }
    return kw;
}
```

So if the keyword is lets say, "Hello". I want this to output /h/e/l/l/o but at the moment its only outputting the last character, in this case /o

Can someone help?

Comment: you should put kw = kw + "/"+letters[i];

that would fix it, but there's probably a much easier way to do it

Comment: On a side note, it would probably be better to have your kw variable be a local variable to the parse function. Especially given that you are returning this value.

Comment: Thank you ROBOSHOP, I forgot recursion can be used with strings as well. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### on `=` vs `+=` and `String` vs `StringBuilder`

Your problem is in this line:

```
 kw = "/"+letters[i];
```

This is a straight assignment, and will overwrite the value of `kw` from the previous iteration. Perhaps you want `+=`. However, at this point you need to know about `StringBuilder` and why doing `+=` with `String` in a loop yields bad performance.

#### Related questions

- [String vs StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder)
- [When to use StringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825781/when-to-use-stringbuilder)

---

#### On regular expressions

If you're up to learning regular expression, you can also do this with one line. You simply match each character `x` and replace it with `/x`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)
- [.NET Framework Class Library - `Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28VS.71%29.aspx)

---

#### Example

Here's a snippet that should be illustrative:

```
   string keyword = "hello";

   foreach (char ch in keyword) {
      Console.Write("[" + ch + "]");
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
   // prints "[h][e][l][l][o]"

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < keyword.Length; i++) {
      sb.Append("<" + keyword[i] + ">");
   }
   Console.WriteLine(sb);
   // prints "<h><e><l><l><o>"

   Console.WriteLine(new Regex(@"(?=.)").Replace(keyword, @"/"));
   // prints "/h/e/l/l/o"

   Console.WriteLine(new Regex(@"(.)").Replace(keyword, @"($1$1)"));
   // prints "(hh)(ee)(ll)(ll)(oo)"
```

Some key ideas:

- Unless you need explicit index, use foreach loop
- When building a string in a loop, use `StringBuilder`
- When properly used, regular expressions are great!

#### References

- [C# Language Reference - foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [.NET Framework Developer's Guide - Using the `StringBuilder` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28VS.71%29.aspx)
- [.NET Framework 4 - Regular Expression Language Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

#### Attachments

- [Source code and output of snippet on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ggWsn)

Comment: I have found the answer; Please see my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you use .NET 4.0, you can do this:

```
string someString = "abc";
string result = string.Join("/", (IEnumerable<char>)someString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public String parse(String keyword)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
        return string.Empty;

    var retVal = (from v in keyword.ToArray()
                    select v.ToString())
                    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "/" +b);

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to optimize this to use less memory by working with chars.

```
public string Parse(string input)
{
    char[] arrResult = new char[input.Length*2];
    int i = 0;
    Array.ForEach<char>(input.ToCharArray(), delegate(char c)
                                                {
                                                    arrResult[i++] = '/';
                                                    arrResult[i++] = c;
                                                });
    return new string(arrResult);
}
```