# Use the += operator to concat strings

Tags: c#, .net, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder)

Why should I not use `+=` to concat strings?

What is the quickest alternative?

Comment: Maybe your question should be more like "When is it appropriate to use `+=` with strings and when not?"

Comment: string newString = stringFirst + stringSecond?? (quickest alternative)

Comment: There are situations where `+=` on strings is appropriate and others where it isn't. See `StringBuilder` for an alternative.

Comment: Even Jon Skeet uses `+` to concatenate string ... [often](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825781/when-to-use-stringbuilder

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in .NET.. which means once they exist, they cannot be changed.

The `StringBuilder` is designed to mitigate this issue, by allowing you to append to a pre-determined character array of *n* size (default is 16 I think?!). However, once the `StringBuilder` exceeds the specified limit.. it needs to allocate a bigger copy of itself, and copy the content into it.. thus creating a possibly bigger problem.

What this boils down to is premature optimization. Unless you're noticing issues with string concatenation's using too much memory.. worrying about it is useless.

Comment: Actually, `"Hello " + "World!"` is exactly 1 string. The compiler does the concat itself.

Comment: ..sigh.. I need to have a coffee. Thanks :) EDIT: I really don't understand why I actually wrote that. I know that.. and somehow forgot. I did the same thing yesterday.. might be time to dust off CLR via C# again.. :/

Answer (score 0):

+= and String1 = String1+String2 do the same thing, copying the whole Strings to a new one.

if you do this in a loop, lots of memoryallocations are generated, leading to poor performance.

if you want to build **long** strings, you should look into the [StringBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) wich is optimized for such operations.

in short: a few concat strings shouldn't hurt performance much, but building a **large** String by adding small bits in a loop will slow you down a lot and/or will use lots of memory.

Another interesting article on String performance: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3377/Strings-UNDOCUMENTED