# How to create connection string dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, connection-string

How to create connection string dynamically in C#, instead of creating it using string concatenation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use StringBuilder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825781/when-to-use-stringbuilder)

Comment: Look at the class [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean `dynamically` ? as in a ConnString that can be changed at runtime, or ?

Comment: ConnString that can be created at runtime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create dynamic connection string with SqlConnectionStringBuilder Class in C# as follows.

for more details pls check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dce36088.aspx

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
     connectionString.DataSource = @".\SQLEXPRESS";
     connectionString.InitialCatalog = "MyDatabase";
     connectionString.IntegratedSecurity = true;
     MessageBox.Show(connectionString.ConnectionString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you better use ADO .NET entity model. check this please:
[Tutoriel ADO .NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=600)