# How to display a string of integers on multiple lines?

Tags: c#, string

My output is a string of integers, displayed consecutively on the same line. Preferably using backslash n, how can I make them be displayed, each on a new line?
This is what I have this far:

```
string even = "";

        while (true)
        {
            string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
            if (inputData.Equals("x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < inputData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (inputData[i] % 2 == 0)
                {
                     even +=inputData[i];

                }
            }

        }
        foreach (var e in even)
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        bool something = string.IsNullOrEmpty(even);
        if( something == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("N/A");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

So, string even, that contains all the even numbers from input should be seen on the console on different lines.
 Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share your current code and also what you have tried. Do you have your ints in a collection of some sort?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly. As it is now, this question can't be answered other then by guessing

Comment: Welcome, Displaying on where place ? Console ?

Comment: my bad. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `string.Join` to create one string out of your numbers string (a string is a collection of characters so you can do so), and specify the separator as [`Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, even.AsEnumerable());
```

---

As a side note, it is not advised to concat a string like that in a loop. Use `StringBuilder`. For explanations why see [When to use StringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825781/6400526) with the many linked questions.

---

Also worth mentioning that though `inputData[i] % 2 == 0` works for you you should remember that `iputData[i]` is a character and not an integer. Therefore the `%` operates on the ASCII representation of the character. For the cases of numbers it works as expected but for instance also `A % 2 == 0` will work.

And if familiar with linq you can refactor is as follows:

```
var even = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, inputData.Select(c => c % 2 == 0));
```

Comment: You may need to convert inputData into Enumerable

Comment: @ManishM - in the first snippet I'm doing so and in the second there is no need :)

Comment: Thank you, this has been really helpful!

Comment: @Anna.A - You are welcome :) did this help you solve the question?

Comment: murphy's law. It worked until I found out that no solutions with linq are accepted. I ended up using another method, but now it doesn't work with multiple-digit numbers :(

Comment: @Anna.A - true but that is due to the input format. If you are just getting digits how can you tell if they are the same number or different numbers :)

Comment: if my input is 12 7 5, the output will be 2. so 12 is treated as 1 and 2. I realize, the problem could be obvious, but I'm only just starting to learn, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @Anna.A - unfortunately this is a followup question and I shouldn't just answer it here. As a hint have a look at `Split`

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple console otuput:

```
foreach (var e in even)
    Console.WriteLine(e);
```

#### Html output

```
var result = "";

foreach (var e in even)
    result += e + "<br>\n";

return Content(result);
```

Comment: @GiladGreen I believe the main problem was mentioned, that a string of numbers needed to be split/displayed in separate lines.