# Convert excel to csv with new line and line break inside a column

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, csv

Trying to convert `xlsx` file to `csv` via C# code. I am able to convert file successfully but it could not handle newline and line break properly.
Please advice which separator to use so that my `csv` is generated correctly

`csv` conversion code could not convert correctly. It should complete the conversion of a column completely but didn't.

using the below code to convert `xlsx` file to `csv`

```
string file= @"fakepath\abc.xlsx";

DataSet result = new DataSet();

//------To read the xlsx file
if (file.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
            {
                // Reading from a binary Excel file (format; *.xlsx)
                FileStream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                excelReader.Close();
            }

//-------To convert the file into csv format
while (row_no < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    a += result.Tables[0].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + ",";
                }
                row_no++;
                a += "\r\n";
            }

string output = @"fakepath\abc.csv";
            StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false);
            csv.Write(a);
            csv.Close();
```

column in excel holds data as

> 1. First Line
> 2. Second Line
> 3. Third Line

excel point i.e. 1,2 and 3 are in same column but different lines

Expected output csv formmat
1. First Line 2. Second Line 3. Third Line

Please help

Comment: Have tried \n as separator but yet not useful..

Comment: How does that relate to SQL Server? If it doesn't please remove the tag.

Comment: For CRLF you need to use ascii #10#13

Comment: Multi-line cell values use 0x010 char (new line) not 0x013, 0x010 char pairs (full carriage returns).

Comment: @RossBush, I believe a CRLF is actually #13#10, not the other way around but in any event, an excel cel use #10 only; the #13 is stripped by overhead.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is

```
         +-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
         |  a    |       |     |     |     |
         |  b    |       |     |     |     |
         |  c    |       |     |     |     |
         +---------------------------------+
         |  d    |       |     |     |     |
         |  e    |       |     |     |     |
         |  f    |       |     |     |     |
         +---------------------------------+
         |  g    |       |     |     |     |
1        |  h    |       |     |     |     |
         |       |       |     |     |     |
         +---------------------------------+
         |       |       |     |     |     |


         +-------+------+------+-----+-----+
         |  a    |   b  |   c  |     |     |
         |       |      |      |     |     |
         +---------------------------------+
         |  d    |  e   |  f   |     |     |
         |       |      |      |     |     |
         +---------------------------------+
         |  g    |  h   |      |     |     |
 2       |       |      |      |     |     |
         +---------------------------------+
         |       |      |      |     |     |
         |       |      |      |     |     |


         +-------+------+------+-----+-----+
         |  abc  |      |      |     |     |
         |       |      |      |     |     |
         +---------------------------------+
         |  def  |      |      |     |     |
 3       |       |      |      |     |     |
         +---------------------------------+
         |  gg   |      |      |     |     |
         |       |      |      |     |     |
         +---------------------------------+
         |       |      |      |     |     |
```

for 1 to 2  USE

```
var column = result.Tables[0].Rows[row_no][i].ToString();
column.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }).ToList()
.ForEach(column_line => { a += column_line + ","; });
```

for 1 to 3  USE

```
var column = result.Tables[0].Rows[row_no][i].ToString();
a += String.Join(" ", column.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }));
```

also for 1 to 3 you can USE

```
var column = result.Tables[0].Rows[row_no][i].ToString();
column = column.Replace("\r", " ");
a+= column.Replace("\n", " ");
```

Full code

```
string file = @"fakepath\abc.xlsx";

DataSet result = new DataSet();

//------To read the xlsx file
if (file.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
{
    // Reading from a binary Excel file (format; *.xlsx)
    FileStream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
    excelReader.Close();
}

//-------To convert the file into csv format
while (row_no < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        var column = result.Tables[0].Rows[row_no][i].ToString();
        //column.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }).ToList().ForEach(column_line => { a += column_line + ","; });
        or
        a+=String.Join(" ", column.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }));
        //or
        //column = column.Replace("\r", " ");
        //a+= column.Replace("\n", " ");

    }
    row_no++;
    a += Environment.NewLine;
    //or
    // a += "\r\n";
}

string output = @"fakepath\abc.csv";
StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false);
csv.Write(a);
csv.Close();
```

More

also

```
a +=Environment.NewLine
```

instead of

```
 a +="\r\n";
```

Comment: Current Output

1. First Line,2. Second Line,3. Third Line

Expected output

1. First Line 2. Second Line 3. Third Line

In excel all these three points are in 1 column, if all values will be separated with comma then if I import it in SQL then I will need 3 columns but it is 1 column value

Comment: do you still need help ?\

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is the most common issue people have when processing CSV files: they think all that is required is to concatenate the values with commas, and put a newline at the end of each line. There are fringe cases they don't think about like:

1. What if a value contains newline?
2. What if a value contains comma?
3. Once they've overcome 1 and 2, what if the value contains `"`?

I'd suggest the best approach would be to use a library to help create the CSV file. But if you don't want to do that, here are some suggestions which may improve things:

1. Each value needs to be enclosed in `"` characters.
2. As a result of point 1, `"` characters within the value need to be escaped with a backslash character before them.
3. The declaration of `a` is not shown, but I assume it to be a string. Strings are immutable, so you [should use System.Text.StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825781/when-to-use-stringbuilder) to construct the string.
4. The code in the question will always end up with an extra comma on the end of each line. Consider using `string.Join` to put commas between the values, so you don't get one on the end.
5. `Stream`s are IDisposable, so each one should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the stream, as it will be closed by the implicit Dispose when it exits the block.
6. Rather than `while (row_no < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count)` prefer `foreach (DataRow dataRow in result.Tables[0].Rows)`. It's easier to read what the loop is doing, and puts the row in a local variable, rather than having to do the property lookup for `Tables` and the indexer lookup for the table, and the property lookup for `Rows` and the indexer lookup each time within the loop. And it makes the contents of the loop easier to read.
7. Use `System.Environment.NewLine` in preference to `"\r\n"`. This is just cosmetic, again, to make it human-readable.

So that would give you...

```
string file= @"fakepath\abc.xlsx";

DataSet result = new DataSet();

//------To read the xlsx file
if (file.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
{
    // Reading from a binary Excel file (format; *.xlsx)
    using (FileStream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        excelReader.Close();
    }
}

//-------To convert the file into csv format
var a = new StringBuilder();
int columnCount=result.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
foreach (DataRow dataRow in result.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var values=new List<string>(columnCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        values.Add(dataRow[i].ToString());
    }
    string line=string.Join(",", values.Select(v=>$"\"{Escape(v)}\"");
    a.AppendLine(line); // even neater than Environment.NewLine
}

string output = @"fakepath\abc.csv";
using(StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false))
{
    csv.Write(a.ToString());
}
```

I'm not at my PC, so cut me some slack if there are typos or autocorrect errors in the above. Also: I have omitted the definition of method `string Escape(string v)`, which needs to do what is described in my point 2.

Comment: Sir, Can u edit the part of the code in the manner you suggested please

Comment: @HrishikeshBagchi Done