# Ideas for implementing wildcard matching in C

Tags: c, regex, string, strtok

I'm looking into writing a program that takes a text, some wildcard patterns and then shows me the words that match those wildcards. The wildcard pattern contains only `.`, which represents only one character, or `*`, which can be anything (including a white space, a new line or `?!,./\` etc.).

Until now, I managed to dynamically read the text and I'm thinking into creating a list with all the words with strtok. Only with `.`, it'd be easy, but I have no idea how to work with `*`. And expressions, of course, can be a combination of `.` and `*`, like this: `h.*.` (which can be a match for `harry` for example).

I'd like you to share some ideas with me. I'm not asking for explicit full code, but for ideas to implement it myself.

Comment: The character `*` by itself is not a valid regular expression, in a regex it's a modifier character that means "zero or more of the previous expression". It's a valid expression when [*globbing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) on the other hand.

Comment: In this problem, if an expression would be only *, it should show me all the words. It's a combination of regular expression and globbing, but only with two wildcards.

Comment: And don't try to make a regular expression engine all by your self, not unless you want to get your hands dirty with finite state machines and automatas and regular languages. Not even a simple globbing system is, well, simple. For globbing, there are functions available, either as part of the C runtime library or as external libraries (depending on system). On POSIX systems (like e.g. Linux or OSX) you could use [`fnmatch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) for globbing.

Comment: You can build a simple *wildcard* matching scheme for * and ? in a few dozen lines of C. A *regular expression* search is considerably harder to implement. I'm sure your university task is the former. Check the exact requirements before delving in.

Comment: Okay, for only `.` (or `?`) and `*` it should be a little simpler. But there are still lots of cases that will be hard, like will `"* bar"` match e.g. `"hello foo bar"` or only `"foo bar"`, for example. You could actually find some source for a `scanf` function, and see how it handles pattern matching.

Comment: I tried to translate what I need in English from my language. Wildcard matching scheme sounds much better :)

Comment: (Meandering thought only) If `.` stands for 'one single character' and `*` for 'one or more', then your sample sequence `h.*.` can be simplified to just `h*`. Do you want to have suffix functionality as well? I.e., `h*y` – literal characters *after* a wildcard?

Comment: @Jongware - No, the first requires at least three characters and the second only two.

Comment: The expressions I have to search for are purely random. Of course, h.*. and h* are equivalent for harry, it was just an example :) Thanks anyone for your help!

Comment: I wrote an implementation in C# you way wish to see. It has numerous features such as multiple queries on the trot, case insensitive support, and efficiency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54820605/848344

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [2001 IOCCC one-liner](http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#2001) (schweikh, ahem) that does globbing with `*` for "zero or more characters" and `?` for "exactly one character".

Figuring out how that one works is probably enlightening and gives you plenty of ideas.

Comment: Amazing! I bet you know by heart the C precedence table :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is pretty simple implementation:

```
int WildcardCompare(const char* wild, const char* string) 
{
    const char* cp = NULL, *mp = NULL;
    
    while ((*string) && (*wild != '*')) 
    {
        if ((*wild != *string) && (*wild != '?')) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        wild++;
        string++;
    }
        
    while (*string) 
    {
        if (*wild == '*') 
        {
            if (!*++wild) 
            {
                return 1;
            }
            mp = wild;
            cp = string+1;
        } 
        else if ((*wild == *string) || (*wild == '?')) 
        {
            wild++;
            string++;
        } 
        else 
        {
            wild = mp;
            string = cp++;
        }
    }
        
    while (*wild == '*') 
    {
        wild++;
    }
    return !*wild;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this as well :)

Comment: I just tried it and there are some...errors. First of all, I get "error: assignment of read-only variable ‘mp’". If I remove "const", it's ok, but a combination of stars and question-marks are fatal for the program. For example, I tried with string = "lampa" and wild="??*mpa" which should return 1, but I get an Segmentation fault error. I'll try to fix something if I can :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at flex and bison. They should help you with tokenizing and then parsing the regex. From there it should be fairly easy to perform the matching.